# I need to find orders without order item

Tags: order

I have lakhs of orders in my org. And it also has its associated order items. So I need to check which orders are not having any of the order items.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can write query like below:

```
select Id,Name from Order where Id not In (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem)
```